# 12vdc Adapters Outputting 12vdc Plus 20vac-23vac Dual Voltage, What's Going On Here?

Tags: voltage

So I have many 12vdc adapters which I buy from the local street which only sells used computer assessories and electronics. I use these adapters for routers, led lights, tiny ventilation fans etc.

Over the years I got several little tingle shocks each time I touch the output leads of these adapters which I learned to ignore. Very recently, I turned the knob of my multimeter to vac for investigation and found out that every single one of these adapters was giving a dual voltage. On the VDC section, it gave 11.5vdc-12.5vdc and on the VAC section, it were giving a reading of between 20vac-23vac.

I have investigated on this and the only explanation I have got is that Y cap next to the transformer maybe of the wrong rating.

Am I the only one to have stumbled on this fact about the commonly sold 12vdc adapters in the market?

Is this normal? For adapters to give dual voltage?

What's going on here?

Comment: A lot of switch mode supplies can produce substantial AC voltages from either output terminal to ground. However, when plugged in to some target system or circuit this voltage drops. Can you confirm exactly how you measured the AC voltage. I suspect that you measured this relative to ground or earth and not from positive to negative on the output leads.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280319/ac-at-output-of-my-power-supply?noredirect=1#comment637655_280319

Answer (score 1):

There are some cheap DVMs that do give a higher reading on AC volts when set to read AC, but used to measure DC. Good meters should read close to zero under these circumstances. (One offending meter previously mentioned here was a UT-33, I think.)

Comment: It is not necessarily related to being cheap.  An accepted way if measuring AC voltages is to perform full-wave rectification, average the resultant value then multiply by a scaling factor to convert to RMS equivalent.  This factor is 1.11 so if you measure a DC voltage it would read about 10% more than the actual DC value.  A true RMS reading would read the correct value.  Also some meters have capacitative coupling to only read the AC component, others don't.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter correctly mentions DMM's measure peak AC then convert to RMS assuming it is a sine wave.  But spikes will read much higher than actual.

What is happening?

Most DC "bricks" are 2 pronged have no ground and thus no Y caps, so the Vac is likely high common mode noise into a 1MOhm DMM resulting DM error from excess CM noise.  Earth Grounding the DC on one side may prove this assumption to be true measurement error.

For the Laptop type 3 pronged bricks then Y caps are used with a max of 0.5mA typically used to reduce conducted line noise emissions.

- if using 120V then  the Y cap impedance is equivalent to 120V/0.5mA= 240K but the DC is isolated by an RF switching transformer with some coupling capacitance to the DC side, so it will have some CM noise pulses modulated by the 120Hz with some xx uA of current if you connect the DC to earth.

  Otherwise with a DMM with 1M load you measure "no load" voltage.  If we assume a few values, we compare open circuit voltage to expected ground short circuit current which you can measure.

e.g.  Voc/Isc = 20Vac/100uA =  0.2M which is the expected impedance value of the Y cap. ( not exact, as the current may be impulses of harmonics at 2f rate and impedance of C drops with each rising harmonic)